# How to vectorize operation with vectors of different size

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have different sized vectors and want to do element-wise manipulations. How can I optimize the following for-loop in Python? (For instance with `np.vectorize()`)

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000000

vec1 = np.random.rand(n)
vec2 = np.random.rand(3*n)
vec3 = np.random.rand(3*n)

for i in range(len(vec1)):
    if vec1[i] < 0.5:
        vec2[3*i : 3*(i+1)] = vec1[i]*vec3[3*i : 3*(i+1)]
    else:
        vec2[3*i : 3*(i+1)] = [0,0,0]
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is, basically, a misnomer in the sense of vectorization being used to speed up code. It's just a python `for` loop under another name. The docs list it as a convenience function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could leverage [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
v = vec3.reshape(-1,3)*vec1[:,None]
m = vec1<0.5
vec2_out = (v*m[:,None]).ravel()
```

Another way to express that would be -

```
mask = vec1<0.5
vec2_out = (vec3.reshape(-1,3)*(vec1*mask)[:,None]).ravel()
```

And use multi-cores with [`numexpr module`](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr) -

```
import numexpr as ne

d = {'V3r':vec3.reshape(-1,3),'vec12D':vec1[:,None]}
out = ne.evaluate('V3r*vec12D*(vec12D<0.5)',d).ravel()
```

Timings -

```
In [84]: n = 1000000
    ...: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: vec1 = np.random.rand(n)
    ...: vec2 = np.random.rand(3*n)
    ...: vec3 = np.random.rand(3*n)

In [86]: %%timeit
    ...: v = vec3.reshape(-1,3)*vec1[:,None]
    ...: m = vec1<0.5
    ...: vec2_out = (v*m[:,None]).ravel()
10 loops, best of 3: 23.2 ms per loop

In [87]: %%timeit
    ...: mask = vec1<0.5
    ...: vec2_out = (vec3.reshape(-1,3)*(vec1*mask)[:,None]).ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 13.1 ms per loop

In [88]: %%timeit
    ...: d = {'V3r':vec3.reshape(-1,3),'vec12D':vec1[:,None]}
    ...: out = ne.evaluate('V3r*vec12D*(vec12D<0.5)',d).ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.11 ms per loop
```

---

For a generic case, where the else-part could be something other than zeros, it would be -

```
mask = vec1<0.5
IF_vals = vec3.reshape(-1,3)*vec1[:,None]
ELSE_vals = np.array([1,1,1])
out = np.where(mask[:,None],IF_vals,ELSE_vals).ravel()
```

Comment: I accepted your answer since it was the first and it gave me the most insight. Maybe one more question. What would you change in the code if we would change the following line: `else: vec2[3*i : 3*(i+1)] = [1,1,1]` ?

Comment: @MalteWinckler Added generic case solution at the end.

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.vectorize`, [as mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57398731/how-to-vectorize-operation-with-vectors-of-different-size/57398980#comment101279031_57398731), is for convenience, not performance, [per the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The `vectorize` function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

One solution to *actually* vectorize this would be:

```
vec2[:] = vec1.repeat(3) * vec3   # Bulk compute all results
vec2[(vec1 < 0.5).repeat(3)] = 0  # Zero the results you meant to exclude
```

Another approach (that minimizes temporaries) would be to filter and reshape `vec1` so it can be assigned to `vec2`, then multiply `vec2` by `vec3` in place to avoid a temporary (beyond the two `n` length arrays from the first step), e.g.:

```
vec2.reshape(-1, 3)[:] = (vec1 * (vec1 >= 0.5)).reshape(-1, 1)
vec2 *= vec3
```

An additional temporary could be shaved if `vec1` can be modified, simplifying to:

```
vec1 *= vec1 >= 0.5
vec2.reshape(-1, 3)[:] = vec1.reshape(-1, 1)
vec2 *= vec3
```

Answer (score 0):

The reshape/broadcasting that @Divakar demonstrates is equivalent to rewriting your iteration as:

```
In [5]: n = 10 
   ...: vec1 = np.random.rand(n) 
   ...: vec2 = np.zeros((n,3)) 
   ...: vec3 = np.random.rand(n,3) 
   ...:  
   ...: for i in range(len(vec1)): 
   ...:     if vec1[i] < 0.5: 
   ...:         vec2[i,:] = vec1[i]*vec3[i,:] 
   ...:     else: 
   ...:         vec2[i,:] = 0 
   ...:                                                                                                      
In [6]: vec2                                                                                                 
Out[6]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.119655  , 0.05079028, 0.00392748],
       [0.04529872, 0.04630456, 0.01565116],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.08361475, 0.21825921, 0.1273483 ]])
In [7]: vec1                                                                                                 
Out[7]: 
array([0.934649  , 0.85309325, 0.50775071, 0.91246865, 0.12970539,
       0.13075136, 0.89861756, 0.68921343, 0.80572879, 0.25996369])
```

By defining `vec2` as a (n,3) array, we replace this indexing `vec2[3*i : 3*(i+1)]` with `vec2[i,:]` or `vec2[i]`.

Use of a `mask` to set values to 0 is a good basic `numpy` idea.  But `ufunc` also provide a `where` parameter that can be used as:

```
In [11]: vec2 = np.zeros((n,3))                                                                              
In [12]: np.multiply(vec1[:,None],vec3, out=vec2, where=vec1[:,None]<0.5);                                   
In [13]: vec2                                                                                                
Out[13]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.119655  , 0.05079028, 0.00392748],
       [0.04529872, 0.04630456, 0.01565116],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.08361475, 0.21825921, 0.1273483 ]])
```

This `where` needs to be used in conjunction with a `out` parameter, since it only does the `multiply` for the True instances.

I'm not sure how much of a time saver it is.